# How to retain input form values on validation fail spring MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, spring-mvc

I am in process of validating in input from and want that the user input fields should be retain in case of validation error

this is how my input fields are

```
<form:input path="firstName" class="text short" id="firstName" value="First Name" name ="firstName"/>
```

my problem is `value="First Name"`, since this is over writing the values which user has filled in and i can not change the HTML , can only add condition in the above input box.

is there any way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you want to display "First Name" as a sort of placeholder until the user enters something in. In that case, why don't you use the `placeholder` html5 attribute?

Answer (score 1):

The attribute value on `<form:input/>` is overriding the value submitted by user coming from the controller.

There are a lot of workarounds: setting the input value with javascript if is not set by user or even using a condition as you said. Maybe this helps:

```
<c:if test="${not empty command.firstName}">
    <form:input path="firstName" cssClass="text short"/>
</c:if>
<c:if test="${empty command.firstName}">
    <form:input path="firstName" cssClass="text short" value="First Name"/>
</c:if>
```

where command is the name of the object coming from controller.